# How to store json output in a variable and use it in another step in Github actions

Tags: json, github-actions, jq

I have a step in github actions that gets a message from sqs queue. The response is an object with a message array. [receive_message_sqs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sqs/receive-message.html) But then I try to get the ReceiptHandle from the object in the array but i keep running into this error.

Here is the step that receives the message

```
     - name: Receive Message from SQS Queue
        id: receive_message
        run: |
          RESPONSE=$(aws sqs receive-message --queue-url https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-queue.fifo \
          --attribute-names All \
          --message-attribute-names All --max-number-of-messages 10 --output json)
          echo "::set-output name=receipt_handle::$RESPONSE"
```

Here is the next step that uses the the Response from the previous step. I want to extract the receipt_handle from the RESPONSE and into a variable and check if it worked. I need the first object in the array

```
      - name: Check ReceiptHandle
        id: check_receipt_handle
        run: |
          RECEIPT_HANDLE=$(echo "${{ steps.receive_message.outputs.receipt_handle }}" | jq -r '.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle')
          if [ -z "$RECEIPT_HANDLE" ]; then
            echo "ReceiptHandle is empty. Failing the workflow."
            exit 1
          else
            echo "ReceiptHandle: $RECEIPT_HANDLE"
          fi
          echo "::set-output name=receipt_handle::$RECEIPT_HANDLE"
```

Here is a screenshot of what the object looks like
[image]

This is the error i am getting back for the check ReceiptHandle step. Looks like something that has to do with json parsing.
[image]

Is there a way to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Try: `RECEIPT_HANDLE=$(jq -r '.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle' <<< '${{ steps.receive_message.outputs.receipt_handle }}')`

Comment: I tried this, but then I get the similar error
`Run RECEIPT_HANDLE=$(jq -r '.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle' <<< '{')
parse error: Unfinished JSON term at EOF at line 2, column 0
Error: Process completed with exit code 4.`

Comment: Then, you need to store the compact JSON to begin with i.e. `RESPONSE=$(aws sqs ... --output json | jq -c)`.

Comment: `set-output` has been deprecated. You should start using `GITHUB_OUTPUT` now. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from [@Azeem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7670262/azeem) resolved my issue:

```
RESPONSE=$(aws sqs ... --output json | jq -c)
```

As I believe some readers might overlook the comment, I've posted it here.